# How to close this wall

Tags: walls, windows, floor, extension

My house has a small "porch" near the main door. In many years I've been here, I never once used this area that is on the North side of the house as a porch. It tends to collect junk that I need to clear out every couple of years (guess how I spent the morning). Just behind that wall however, there is my master bathroom, that is the smallest a bathroom can practically be: 5x7 feet. I am seriously considering starting a project to enclose that space and expand the bathroom a little.

If I do this however, I plan to do it on my own, requesting all the necessary permits. It's the first time I'd do something like this.

My question is: how would one enclose that area? I guess under the stucco, that I suspect is 1/2 to one inch thick, there must be a lumber structure. Would I need to rip everything apart and simply rebuild it from scratch? Note from the pictures the area is already covered by the existing roof so I will not have to touch that, and it is for this reason I believe I'll be able to do this on my own. I will want to add a window.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is fairly easy since you have that big header holding the roof up. You would remove the stucco on the header, at the bottom I would probably pull the trim exposing the frame of that short wall. Then I would build a wall with the opening for your window in the space and stucco the outside, once that is sealed up you could open the wall of the bathroom and remove the stucco then finish the floor to ceiling wall inside the porch area, since you are not modifying a load bearing wall you may not need a permit, that is one of the qualifications for getting a permit in my area. But this looks like it is a good idea to me. Check with your building codes department.

Comment: I see, I will most definitely ask for the permits now that I know this might be within the realm of possibility. Now, I'm off to a popular streaming website looking up "how to remove stucco" :D

Comment: Stucco is easy it is usually a layer of wire mesh attached to the stud with a vapor barrier or expanded metal that a mortar /concrete mixture is pressed into, after the base coat an additional top layer that many times has a colored mixture so no painting is required for decades, I will use an angle grinder to cut a straight line then a hammer and a wonder bar a type of flat crow bar to pop the stucco off the studs, the toughest is the expanded metal that was popular until the 50’s from the remodels I did just north of your area in my early construction years. Disposal is harder than removal.

Comment: You'd use a regular cutting disc with the angle grinder? I thought I'd start with a hammer but the grinder is likely to be much faster.
However this made me think I am not up to the task to redo the stucco on the new wall. I'll have to hire somebody - how easy is it to match an existing stucco that in my case has been redone by the previous owner ~10 years ago?

Comment: Matching is the toughest part numbers especially if the pigment is in the mix if painted not as tough.